# Does "Aren't you a silly girl!" mean "You aren't a silly girl!"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, negation, inversion, exclamatives

my example:
**(1a)** *Are you a silly girl*!
As I understand, (1a) means (1b):
**(1b)** *You are a silly girl*!

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/boy-was-i-wrong.808983/post-4370437):
**(2a)** *Aren't you a silly girl*!
Am I right that, by analogy with (1a), (2a) means (2b)?:
**(2b)** *You aren't silly girl*!
If not, then why not?

---

the same question about one more example:

my example:
**(3a)** *Is it a lovely day*!
As I understand, (3a) means (3b):
**(3b)** *It is a lovely day*!

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/boy-was-i-wrong.808983/post-4370437):
**(4a)** *Isn't it a lovely day*!
Am I right that, by analogy with (3a), (4a) means (4b)?:
**(4b)** *It isn't a lovely day*!
If not, then why not?

---

an update:
The question is about the meaning of negative and positive exclamatives having inversion, but not about interrogatives.
The question is about what meaning an exclamative will have if we invert its word order.
The question is about how the meaning of an exclamative will change if we apply inversion.

Comment: The punctuation does not change the meaning, or the answers already provided below.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. Even worse. If the asker is really trying to force these sentences into not being a question, they are just straight up ungrammatical.

Comment: Where did you get examples 1a and 3a from? They're not grammatical as far as I can tell since they're questions but they don't have question marks. On the other hand, 2a and 4a don't *really* need question marks since they're rhetorical: they're not *really* questions.

Answer (score 10):

To answer your question title first - no, one does not equal the other, in fact the opposite. "Aren't you a silly girl?" means "I think you are a silly girl and I'm telling you this, albeit indirectly."

2 and 4 are [rhetorical questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question). They don't need an answer, but the presumed answer is affirmative. They also ought to have question marks rather than exclamation marks, unless they are supposed to be actual exclamations, for emphasis.

If they did require answers, these are the answers expected.

> Aren't you a silly girl?
> Yes, I am a silly girl.

> Isn't it a lovely day?
> Yes, it is a lovely day. The sun is shining.

1 and 3 are *actual* direct questions and would appear to need an answer, but that answer doesn't have to be affirmative.

> Are you a silly girl?
> No, I'm highly intelligent and mature for my age.

> Is it a lovely day?
> No, it's raining.

The 'aren't you and 'isn't it' constructions are not the direct opposites of 'are you' and 'is it', so swapping them does not reverse the meaning.

In speech, 1 and 3 *could* be voiced rhetorically, but simply as written and with no other context, they are more direct questions.

Comment: Could you tell me please why you replaced all exclamation marks with question marks? The original question is about the meaning of negative and positive exclamatives having inversion, but not about interrogatives.

Comment: That's covered in the Wikipedia link - I'm just one of those who insists on a question mark, unless the context is clearly exclamatory. There's not enough context in those short snippets to clearly define, so I stuck to the question mark. It's not that important to the overall meaning, it's stylistic.

Comment: [cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/exclamations) : "_Have I got news for you! Peter and Michaela are getting divorced_!" The site says "_Have I got news for you_!"≈ "_I’ve got news for you_!". That is, it doesn't relate to a rhetorical question. It relates to the exclamative inversion was applied to.

Comment: You're arguing over the wrong thing.

Comment: I don't argue. I just don't understand. The site says "_Have I got news for you_!"≈ "_I’ve got news for you_!". But by your logic, this is wrong and the right meaning must be "_Have I got news for you_!"≈ "_Have I got news for you_?" That's why I'm totally confused.

Comment: I covered this in my first comment above. I'm really not sure how else I can say it. If it is indeed an exclamation, then some writers will use an exclamation mark. Some will not. There is no other difference in the perception/parsing/meaning of the actual sentence.

Comment: @Loviii: Grammatically, they are questions ("aren't you" instead of "you aren't" word order). The choice to write them in the original with exclamation points rather than question marks was an odd one, but probably intended to convey the speaker's intonation.

Comment: The proper punctuation would probably be an interrobang, since "Aren't you a silly girl?" is often exclamatory. That was invented in the 1960's, but I think the idiom is much older.

Answer (score 3):

Although grammatically one is an inversion of the other, idiomatically they do not mean the same thing. The first is a rhethorical question i.e one that is not seeking an answer, but used to make a point.

It is more easily understood if you begin by considering a non-rhetorical example:

*The machine is still not working. Why? Hasn't it been repaired?* The last sentence unabbreviated is *Has it not been repaired?*

*Aren't I an idiot?* is the kind of thing you say when you suddenly realise you have made a stupid mistake. It does not call for an answer but don't be surprised if someone says *Yes you are an idiot!*

Similarly if someone else makes an obvious mistake you might say *Aren't you a silly girl?* *Are you not a silly girl?* Gramatically this would mean  *You are a silly girl!*, but it lacks the emphatic and rhetorical quality of the former.

Comment: Could you tell me please why you replaced all exclamation marks with question marks? The original question is about the meaning of negative and positive exclamatives having inversion, but not about interrogatives.

Comment: @Loviii These are rhetorical questions. Rhetorical questions aren't true interrogatives, although they follow the form of a question and require a question mark, no answer is actually expected. They are used for effect.

Comment: @BillyKerr [cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/exclamations) : "_Have I got news for you! Peter and Michaela are getting divorced_!" The site says "_Have I got news for you_!"≈ "_I’ve got news for you_!". It does not say this relates to a rhethorical question. As far as I understood, the example just shows that we can replace the usual non-inverted word order in an exclamative with inversion without changing the meaning. Could you explain to me please why I am wrong?

Comment: @Loviii That doesn't work with negative rhetorical questions. "Aren't you a silly girl" = "You are a silly girl".

Comment: The difference is that "Aren't you a silly girl!" is still fundamentally a negative rhetorical *question* (hence the inversion); the punctuation is used to show a particular verbal emphasis, used with this sort of negative rhetorical question *to emphasize that it is rhetorical*. However, "Have I got news for you!" is **not** a positive rhetorical question, and **not** showing emphasis on an equivalent form "Have I got news for you?". The latter would rarely be said at all, and makes it sound like the speaker is confused (can't recall whether or not there is news for the listener).

Comment: Aside from that: negative and positive rhetorical questions generally *both imply the positive* - in the same way that negative and positive requests are understood the same way by the speaker ("Won't you come with me?" is seen as more polite than "will you come with me?", but means the same rather than the opposite). *This works the same way in many other languages* - even including Japanese, which is overall extremely "logical" about double negation.

Comment: @Loviii I think *Have I got news for you?* is a rhetorical question, which similarly to the example under discussion, introduces inversion to create emphasis.

Comment: Just to add to the controversy/discussion/lack of importance, the famous British TV show [Have I Got News For You](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Have_I_Got_News_for_You) (now in its 65th season) uses no punctuation at all...

Comment: One amusing example of how this has changed over time: some Bible translations from the Early Modern period needed to be revised in modern English, replacing “Is it not so?” (which today means that it obviously is) with “This is not so, is it?” (which means it obviously isn’t).

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have been correct, grammatically speaking, but come short of fully explaining a key point relative to questions in English.

**Questions in the Negative**

When asking something in the negative, it can be understood as *challenging* or as *presumptive* (assuming the truth of the statement).  In either case, the question might be considered *rhetorical*, but it can still be answered, particularly if the one answering disagrees with its assumption.

For example:

- *Didn't you eat breakfast already?*  (Challenging: Expresses disbelief at someone still eating breakfast.)
- *Wouldn't you like some ice cream?* (Presumptive: Assumes the person asked would indeed like some.)

In a *challenging* case, an exclamation mark could also be used, with no change to its meaning.  However, to use an exclamation mark with a *presumptive* case would alter its meaning.

Consider:

- *Wouldn't you like some ice cream!* (This may imply the person has already expressed desire for the ice cream, but it also implies that the ice cream is unavailable to the one desiring it.)
- *Don't you wish!*  (This expresses an unreal condition--whatever it is that is wished for is not the reality of the situation.)

Note that, unlike other negative questions in English, such as negative tag questions, answering a presumptive question affirmatively *agrees* with the question's assumption, whereas answering it negatively *disagrees* with it.

Examples:

- *You aren't hungry, are you?* (Negative **tag question**: Answering "no" agrees with the questioner's assumption that you are **not** hungry; answering "yes" *disagrees* with that assumption and says that actually, yes, you *are* hungry.)
- *Aren't you hungry?* (Presumptive question: Answering "Yes, I am hungry" *agrees* with the assumption; answering "no" *disagrees*, and says that one is not in fact hungry.  Remember, the assumption of the question is that you *are* hungry.)

**In the OP's Examples:**

(1a) Are you a silly girl!  (Incorrect punctuation--this one must be a question mark.)

(1b) You are a silly girl!  (Correct as an exclamatory statement.)

**[ (1a) and (1b) are not the same. ]**

(2a) Aren't you a silly girl!  (Correct as a challenging/exclamatory statement.)

(2b) You aren't silly girl!  (Incorrect punctuation/grammar.  Corrected: "You aren't silly, girl!" OR "You aren't a silly girl!")

**[ (2a) and (2b) have opposite meanings; (1b) and (2a) have nearly identical meaning. ]**

(3a) Is it a lovely day!  (Incorrect punctuation--this one must be a question mark.)

(3b) It is a lovely day! (Correct as an exclamatory statement.)

(4a) Isn't it a lovely day! (Correct as a challenging/exclamatory statement.)

(4b) It isn't a lovely day! (Correct as a challenging/exclamatory statement.)

**[ (4a) and (4b) have opposite meanings; (3b) and (4a) have nearly identical meaning. ]**

**Disclaimer:** This is my own explanation, and terminology.  Some might call *presumptive questions* "[suggestive questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suggestive_question)"--though I find that to incompletely describe the grammatical usage, as what I call a "presumptive" question may have no intention of *suggesting* anything; rather, it may show surprise or be a form of courtesy, e.g. *"Wouldn't you like a glass of water?"* may be considered more formal and polite than *"Do you want a glass of water?"*; although *"Would you like a glass of water?"* would also express the same courtesy without the assumption.

Comment: These might look very similar in writing, but there's often significant differences in prosody ([particularly intonation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question#Intonation)) when spoken.  I'd imagine something like "Ain't that the truth?" or "Aren't you a silly girl?" would be a falling intonation tag question.

Comment: @DavidA Certainly tone is difficult to represent or discern in textual communication.  Another point that I could have made concerns the _challenging_ tag question--the exception to the rule of the tag being opposite in affirmativeness/negativeness as compared to the question's statement.  With a challenge tag, both sides are positive/affirmative, e.g. "So, you think you will beat me, do you?"  The tone on a challenge tag would typically be fall-rising, as in a standard "yes" or "no" type question.